# Merging two cells in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layouts, table

[image][image][image]

I want to merge 2 cells and I can't seem to find anything online, what should I do exactly?

Comment: It's not an attribute table, its a table made directly in layout, I'm adding a screenshot

Comment: You should add some more details about how this table has been created. For example, the source of the data.

Comment: I created it directly in my layout and it doesn't have any source, I want to know if I can merge the cells in table designer

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the empty second column?

Comment: No, only on the first row I need to merge it with the text because I will later add text in the other cells

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that it's easier to do this with HTML rather than trying to find something that doesn't exist.